# PHP - listing every item a user has posted

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and trying to learn some so sorry if this seems like too easy a question! anyway lets say I have 2 tables -

- ID & author
- ID, joke and AID (supposed to be Author ID)

I want to display each author and each joke they have written all on the same page

**Author**

- joke
- joke
- joke

**Author**

- joke
- joke
- joke

How would I go about doing this? I just can't figure it out and I don't know how to google it because I don't know how to word it. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be super. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to fetch the data from the tables, or how to output it in the format you have presented?

Comment: I wasn't sure on both the PHP and MySQL required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. You query all the `joke`s with their respective `author`

```
    SELECT j.joke, a.author, a.id auth_id
      FROM Jokes j
INNER JOIN Authors a
        ON j.AID = a.ID
  ORDER BY a.ID
```

#### 2. Iterate over the results and output it

```
$last_author_id = -1;
while($row /* your weapon of choice */){
    if($row['auth_id'] != $last_author_id){
        $last_author_id = $row['auth_id'];
        echo $row['author'];
    }
    echo $row['joke'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You join the Authors table (ID and Author) with the Jokes table (ID, joke and AID) on the Foreign Key (author ID)

```
SELECT Joke 
from Authors 
join Jokes
on Authors.ID= Jokes.AID
```

If you don't know your way around SQL I'd recommend a PHP framework if possible, it can simplify the logic and makes your app a lot safer if the framework generates (safe) sql for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to get the information you need:

```
SELECT author, joke 
FROM table1
  JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.AID;
```

If you don't know the PHP-part I'd recommend doing some experiments from a tutorial and then get back when you get stuck